# Find the points of inflection and discuss the concavity of the graph of the function $f(x) = \sin(x/2), x \in [0, 4\pi]$

Tags: calculus

> Find the points of inflection and discuss the concavity of the graph of the function $$f(x) = \sin\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$$ where $x\in [0, 4\pi]$.

I've been trying to figure out this problem and I'm not getting anywhere.

what do I do?

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, *etc.*; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult [this link](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9959) for further guidance.

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Please [edit] your question to show what you have attempted.  For instance, have you found the first and second derivatives.  Have you performed a line analysis to find the sign of the second derivative?  Where does it change sign?